# tkinter shows data from tcp

Tags: python, tkinter, tcp

I wanted to write a program that downloads data via tcp. The received data is a two-part string, time and reference name(f. The last three times are saved and the average is counted from them. I would like to display this average value using Tkinter. The problem lies in refreshing Tkinter window itself. I tried using after() method but I am missing something. How can I update Tkinter window?

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.15'
TCP_PORT = 62
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
data = b' '

ctab = [0]       
n = 3        
def tcp_odbior():
    global data
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)        
    dane_str = data.decode("utf-8")       
    return dane_str

def licznik(zm1): 
    global srednia_ct
    global n
    dl_tab = len(ctab)
    if zm1>120:
        print("przerwa lub za długi postój")
    else:
        if (dl_tab > (n-1)):
            del ctab[0]     
            ctab.append(round(zm1,1))
            srednia_ct = round((sum(ctab) / dl_tab),1)
        else:
            ctab.append(round(zm1,1))
            srednia_ct = round((sum(ctab) / dl_tab),1)
    print(ctab)
    print(srednia_ct)
    return srednia_ct

def counter(label):
    def count():
        global srednia_ct
        dane_plc = tcp_odbior()             
        czas_szt = float(dane_plc[:4])      
        licznik(czas_szt)       
        if dane_plc.find('psa') ==1:               #czas dop. dla psa
            CTref  = 3
        elif dane_plc.find('mnb') == 1:           #czas dop. dla mnb
            CTref = 8
        elif dane_plc.find('fiat') == 1:             #czas dop. dla fiat
            CTref = 15
        if srednia_ct > CTref:
            kolor = "red"
        else:
            kolor = "green"
        label.config(fg = kolor, textvariable=str(srednia_ct))
        label.after(1, count)
    count()
##  EXAMPLE STRING '16.1psa'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

root.title("Licznik")
label = tk.Label(root, bg="white", font="Verdana 100 bold")
label.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
counter(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text="stop", command = root.destroy) 
button.pack(fill=tk.X)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed code a little bit. Now its in only one function. It works when the average time is exceeded, it is displayed in red if not in green. Only problems for now:
1. I cannot use exit button when connection is enabled, when server shutsdown i can use button and close tkinter window.
2. the label is displayed after the fourth data transmission.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import socket

root = Tk()
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.15'
TCP_PORT = 62
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
data = b' '  
ctab = [0]  
n = 3  

def counter(label):
    def count():
        global srednia_ct
        global data
        global n
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        dane_str = data.decode("utf-8") 
        czas_szt = float(dane_str[:4]) 
        ref = dane_str[4:]
        dl_tab = len(ctab)
        if czas_szt > 100:
            print("breakdown ")
        else:
            if (dl_tab > (n - 1)):
                del ctab[0]
                ctab.append(round(czas_szt, 1))  
                srednia_ct = round((sum(ctab) / dl_tab), 1)
            else:
                ctab.append(round(czas_szt, 1))
                srednia_ct = round((sum(ctab) / dl_tab), 1)
        if ref == 'psa':  
            CTref = 17
        elif ref == 'mnb': 
            CTref = 27
        elif ref == 'fiat':  
            CTref = 40
        if srednia_ct > CTref:
            kolor = "red"
        else:
            kolor = "green"
        ref_ostatni = ref
        label.config(fg=kolor, text=str(srednia_ct))
        label.after(10, count)
    count()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
root.title("Licznik")
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) 
label = Label(root, bg="white", font="Verdana 400 bold")
label.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
counter(label)
button = Button(root, text="stop", command=root.destroy)
button.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```